# Kotlin 1.4.20 gradle kts issue in IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, kotlin1.4

I am facing constant issues with my build.gradle.kts where the whole thing is basically red since I migrated to kotlin 1.4.20. Also, the gradle version is 6.7.1.

Any one face similar issues or is it just me? any workarounds?

when run through the cli, the build works perfectly fine but in IntelliJ, the whole thing is red

Exception in IntelliJ

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: declarationDescriptor is null for constructor = TypeVariable(K) with class org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.inference.model.TypeVariableTypeConstructor
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.descriptorUtils.DescriptorUtilsKt.getJetTypeFqName(descriptorUtils.kt:23)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.descriptorUtils.DescriptorUtilsKt$getJetTypeFqName$typeArgumentsAsString$joinedTypeArguments$1.fun(descriptorUtils.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.descriptorUtils.DescriptorUtilsKt$getJetTypeFqName$typeArgumentsAsString$joinedTypeArguments$1.fun(descriptorUtils.kt)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.text.StringUtil.join(StringUtil.java:1337)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.text.StringUtil.join(StringUtil.java:1327)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.text.StringUtil.join(StringUtil.java:1307)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.descriptorUtils.DescriptorUtilsKt.getJetTypeFqName(descriptorUtils.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.hdfsplugin.highlight.kotlin.KotlinSignatureCondition.getReturnTypeFqn(KotlinSignatureCondition.kt:18)
    at org.jetbrains.hdfsplugin.highlight.kotlin.KotlinSignatureCondition.getReturnTypeFqn(KotlinSignatureCondition.kt:8)
    at org.jetbrains.hdfsplugin.highlight.SignatureCondition.checkCondition(SignatureCondition.kt:7)
    at org.jetbrains.hdfsplugin.highlight.inspection.invalidFormat.InvalidFormatInspection.visitCall(InvalidFormatInspection.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.hdfsplugin.highlight.inspection.invalidFormat.KotlinHdfsInvalidFormatInspection$buildVisitor$1.visitCallExpression(KotlinHdfsInvalidFormatInspection.kt:15)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitCallExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:803)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitorVoid.visitCallExpression(KtVisitorVoid.java:21)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallExpression.accept(KtCallExpression.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElementImpl.accept(KtElementImpl.java:51)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEngine.acceptElements(InspectionEngine.java:65)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEngine.createVisitorAndAcceptElements(InspectionEngine.java:56)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.runToolOnElements(LocalInspectionsPass.java:296)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.lambda$visitPriorityElementsAndInit$3(LocalInspectionsPass.java:265)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.forceAllowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:155)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.forceAllowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:147)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.lambda$visitPriorityElementsAndInit$4(LocalInspectionsPass.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.disallowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:126)
    at com.intellij.util.AstLoadingFilter.disallowTreeLoading(AstLoadingFilter.java:115)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.lambda$visitPriorityElementsAndInit$5(LocalInspectionsPass.java:264)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.execAndForkSubTasks(ApplierCompleter.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1110)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$wrapInReadActionAndIndicator$1(ApplierCompleter.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:629)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:581)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.wrapInReadActionAndIndicator(ApplierCompleter.java:117)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$compute$0(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:182)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.compute(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:746)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:
```

Comment: Did you configure the Kotlin version in IntelliJ? Latest kotlin plugin?

Comment: Can you show several last idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action) files? Does it happen with ope project or all (even new) projects?

Comment: Happens only for kotlin 1.4.20 projects

Comment: also, the jetbrains plugin for kotlin crashes

Comment: Exception is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/BDIDE-1074, Big Data Tools plugin is responsible: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12494-big-data-tools

Comment: invalidating cache is the solution i was given

Comment: I upgraded my Intellij and did an `invalidate and restart`. That solved it

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete IDEA cache folder:

```
~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/<product><version> on macOS
~/.cache/JetBrains/<product><version> on Linux
%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\<product><version> on Windows
```

If it doesn't help, please file an issue in [Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=ktij).

Comment: this did not help